# My PS3 will not start

Tags: ps3

When I turn on my PS3 the green light stays on for 2 seconds and then just beeps 3 times and turns off.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Does the green light change colors? 3 beeps plus a yellow light means an overheating issue.

Answer (score 1):

3 beeps is a POST (ps3 equivalent) failure. It generally indicates a terminal problem with the unit and is most commonly caused by heat-related issues having caused the GPU or CPU to have become unseated.

Here is a guide how to fix it, I am not sure if it helps, but it will be good to try:
https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Fixing+Playstation+3+Green+Light+of+Death+(GLOD)/5163